# How to spy on history object from outside the component that uses Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs

For unit tests on other components I use `spyOn` with the `history` module:

```js
 import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
 import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";
 import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
 import Home from "./pages/Home";

 test("home", () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory();
  const pushSpy = jest.spyOn(history, "push");

  render(
   <Router history={history}>
    <Home />
   </Router>
   );

  userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button"));

  expect(pushSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
 }
```

I have the following component where I want to test an invocation to `history.push()`:

```js
function App() {
 return (
  <Router>
   <Switch>
    <Route path="/">
     <Home /> //this component uses history.push internally but it is not wrapped in a router
    </Route>
   </Switch>
  </Router>
 )
}
```

How can I `spyOn` the `history` object when I can't wrap the `App` component with my custom `<Router history={history}>` ?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by putting the custom `history` object on a file that I import both in my test file and my component file:

```js
//testutils.js

import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";

const history = createMemoryHistory();

export default history;
```

I import the custom `history` object in `App`:

```js
//App.jsx

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import history from "./testutils";

function App() {
 return (
  <Router history={history}>
   <Switch>
    <Route path="/">
     <Home /> //this component uses history.push internally but it is not wrapped in a router
    </Route>
   </Switch>
  </Router>
 )
}
```

I also import the custom `history` object in my test file so I can `spyOn` the same object:

```js
import history from "./utils/history";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./outsidehistory";

test("Spy on history from utils file", () => {
  const pushSpy = jest.spyOn(history, "push");
  render(<App />);
  expect(pushSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/success");
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of a spy? Since you have access to `history` in use, you could just assert its state.

Comment: Note you now have an import from "test utils" *in your production code*. It would be much easier to move the Router *out* of App.js.

Comment: To answer @EstusFlask's question, it can be important to ensure redirect(s) is correct rather than just relying on the final destination being correct. You need a spy for that, or a mock (which looses the ability to use the router).